# HTML Chrome Big Border around hyperlink

Tags: html

I don't know why, but it happens! When I open my soon-to-be site in Chrome there is a huge border around hyperlinks that looks like this. Also the link is on a second line!
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpbpP.png)

Thank you for reminding me to put info Steven!
Full detail
CSS Code :

```
padding: 4px;
}

#main {
padding: 6px;
padding-left: 16px;
padding-right 16px;
background-color: #999999;
border-radius: 0 0 6px;
}

h1 {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
border-bottom 3px solid #cc9900;
color: #996600;
font-size: 30px;
}

ul {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%; 

    overflow: auto;

}


li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
li {
    float: middle;
}

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
body {background-color:lightgrey;}
h1 {color:red;}
p {color:blue;}
```

I think CSS is the issue, and since I am using the computer I cannot tell you the HTML.

Comment: Can you provide some code examples such as a snippet of the HTML and your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Yup.  The specified CSS says that within a List Item (often called a bullet point), an Anchor hyperlink should be displayed in its own block, and have some "padding" (borders) of 8 to 16px.  Find the relevant CSS in your web site's code, and remove (or "comment out") the lines that say "display: block" and "padding:" within the "li a" ("List Item", "Anchor") section.  If you want to, you can (but shouldn't need to) keep a "display:" line within that section, but make it say "display:inline;".

Comment: My answer is still confident.  The expected effect of the CSS that you provided are results like what you post.  If you aren't noticing the change, then you're not effectively changing the right CSS.  You might want to try Firefox's debugging tools, as I do believe there is a real-time CSS editor in there.  The other thing is that CSS can overlap and be quite tricky, so you may be loading CSS code from multiple files.  You might need to find another spot where the CSS is also defined, and change it there (too).

Comment: Hmmmm..... Tell Me if there's any issues with this.
li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: Oh! I fixed it! Thanks!